# How to unable npm output color

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, output

I've been looking around for a long time about my problem but I found no solution.
Here it is:

I'm using Jenkins to launch a nodejs API on my server.
In my build, I use a shell script that installs the project and then launches it. The output is redirected into a logfile: "npm start > api.log &"

But, npm provides a formated output with color codes:

> ^[[0mGET route ^[[32m200 ^[[0m60.054 ms - 1739^[[0m

As we consult the logs into a plain text format, this makes the reading harder.

I found many solutions saying to disable the colors of npm like this:

- npm config set color false
- npm --no-color start

But in every case, the color codes still remain.

As a comparison, I set the color to true and the output is exactly the same.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can finally make these colors codes disappear ?

Cheers

Comment: Where do you run `npm config set color false`? And also, with what permissions? These two factors might affect whether the change is actually successful or not.

Comment: I thought about the rights too but even with sudo the result was the same.
Thank you for this precision about the way it works. It seems logical.